# after ajax success refresh / reload page but prevent page blink

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

as title you see, I meet some problem with my website,

I use **ajax** to read my API, and after ajax success, I need to reload page to display some data,

Unfortunately, the page sometime will blink and then reload, but sometime will not.

And I use setTimeout to achieve that, because I'm writing shopping cart page,

It allow user edit their shopping carts' goods.

My idea is: **after user stop click plus or minus button or stop typing quantity about 1 second,**

**ajax will execute to read my API, after ajax success, reload page.**

So, is there have any ways to prevent page blink?

Or maybe I can made a loading gif to display on the page?

My code will be like:

```
var timeout = null;
$('.num').on('keyup', function() {
    var newNum = $(this).val();
    var pid = $(this).attr("name");

    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        if(newNum <= 0){
            alert("At least 1 product!");
            $(this).val("1");
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: myAPI,
                async: false,
                data: {
                    pid: pid,
                    newNum: 1
                },
                dataType: "json",
                success:function(data){
                    window.location.reload(true);                
                },
            });
        }else {
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: myAPI,
                async: false,
                data: {
                    pid: pid,
                    newNum: newNum
                },
                dataType:"json",
                success:function(data){
                    window.location.reload(true);                    
                },
            });
        }
    }, 1000)
});
```

Comment: Why instead of reload whole page you don't create a function for load data then use that function on success ajax ?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini I reload whole page if ajax success

Comment: _"I need to reload page to display some data,"_ - What you should do is to fetch the data in your Ajax response and then update the contents on the page using JS. The whole point of using Ajax is to avoid a page refresh (which will cause blinking/flashing).

Comment: Indeed, page blinks are a result of the reload, and often because very complex or buggy HTML. The normal method is to use the AJAX call, to retrieve what changes on the page, and update only that.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson But I check my website, if ajax success, I use console.log to print my data, it's not working, but if reload page, it can work

Comment: X/Y problem....

Answer (score 0):

You can add a loader gif as you want then remove when document loaded.

```
<div class="loader-fix" style="position:fixed;height:100vh;width:100vw;background:#ffffff;">
        <img src="your.gif" />
</div>
```

```
<script>
        $(window).on('load', function (e) {

            $('.loader-fix').fadeOut('slow', function () {
                $(this).remove();
            });
        });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the point in using `ajax` when you want to reload the page to show updated data...?

```
success:function(data){
                    window.location.reload(true);                    
                }
```

What is the use of above piece of code..?

For your purpose a simple `form submission` thing was enough, but you have used `ajax` getting data but not using it anywhere.

If you want to reload the page, then better go with solution by Şahin Ersever.

If you want a dynamic site, where data is fetched from backend in background and updated on frontend without refreshing the page, do something like this.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1> Dynamic load using AJAX </h1>
    <div class="dynamic_div"> 
      <div class="some_class">
        <!-- here some more elements may/may not contain dynamic data or some server side based-->
         <!-- Like this -->
         <h1> Name:- <?php echo $name;?> </h1>
         <p> <?php echo $some_other_variable;?> </p>
         <p> <?php echo $some_other_variable;?> </p>
         ....
        </div>
    </div>
    <button onclick="letsload()">Load</button>
    <script>
      function letsload(){
         $.post("someurl",{ data1: "value1", data2 : "value2"},
            function(data, status){
              if(status == "success"){
                 $('.dynamic_div').html(data);//Loading updated data
             }
         });
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

On `data` variable, you can echo out desired html/json or a success/error code, and handle the data/code in ajax function accordingly.

**Edit :-**

Looking at your comment `But I check my website, if ajax success, I use console.log to print my data, it's not working, but if reload page, it can work`.

I have a quick and easy solution for this.

Let's take above example, which I have given.

Suppose if I want updated data to be displayed in `dynamic_div` what I will do, is I keep the element to be shown inside that div in separate file.

eg:- updated.php

```
<div class="some_class">
<!-- here some more elements may/may not contain dynamic data or some server side based-->

<!-- Like this -->

<h1> Name:- <?php echo $name;?> </h1>
<p> <?php echo $some_other_variable;?> </p>
<p> <?php echo $some_other_variable;?> </p>
....
</div>
```

Now What I do is on success of my ajax, I will load this div in to my `.dynamic_div` like this.

```
success:function(data){
                    $('.dynamic_div').load("updated.php");//Load the inside elements into div                
                }
```

Now you will get updated data, as you have already updated it somewhere in backend, so `load()` will load a page inside a division, without refreshing the whole page.

Comment down for any queries.

Comment: Now I can get my ajax success data, I'm trying now.

Comment: @ChaCha It becomes very hard to answer, when we don't have information on how the data is structured, since you can `echo` out `html/json/strings/codes` to ajax call. If you show me how the data is ie: output of `console.log(data);` it will be easy to help.

Comment: I already solved this problem, thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

- AJAX Read data from a web server - after a web page has loaded
- Update a web page without reloading the page
- Send data to a web server in the background

[What is Ajax](https://www.w3schools.com/whatis/whatis_ajax.asp)

If you want to reload page then don't use ajax call,
but if you want to load data using ajax then update your html using JavaScript in ajax success message.